# using middleware in express static is not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node js. I'm trying to create a node js app and configured the app.js as follows.

```
var express = require ('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('resources'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I'm using several partial views and inject all the partials to main.ejs and finally inject main.ejs into index.ejs

To apply bootstrap and jquery to all the views, I'm calling them in the index.ejs file.

Index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New page</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="/resources/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <% include main.ejs %>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% include partials/partial_page.ejs %>
</body>
</html>
```

partial_page.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New page partial</title>
</head>
<body>
    New Page 2
    <button class="btn btn-primary">AAAA</button>
</body>
</html>
```

All the static files are stored in resources folder.

These bootstraps and jquery is not working and I can't get any result from them.
**Console has 404 error which is Bootstraps and jquery cannot be found.** What is the wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `<!DOCTYPE>`, `html`, `head`, and `body` tags from all except `index.ejs`. You don't need them since the partials are being rendered inside `index.ejs`, and that's where your route is pointing.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console when you load your page?

Comment: console has 404 error. Bootstraps and jquery cannot be found

Comment: Ok then its most likely an issue with the paths you provided in your `link` and `script` tags. can you demonstrate your project folder layout in the question?

Answer (score 1):

you can  use  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));`

change `<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried it. But still the problem is there

Comment: I updated my question. The error is 404 error. Bootstraps and jquery cannot be found

Comment: change `<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>` and  use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));`

Comment: Tried and still it can't find these files

Comment: I also tried with app.use('/resources', express.static('resources')); and doesn't working

Comment: in your console how  the request is made `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap.min.js` or `http://localhost:3000/resources/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: check if resources directory contains these files or not and add double underscore dirname `__dirname` in `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));`

Comment: Update to these `<link type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require ('express');

var app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname,'resources'));
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);
```